# Fake the url bar with ajax and window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window.location

I make a ajax request with .load. It is working good. But i have a problem with the url bar. I want change the url bar. For example. When the ajax loads about/contact page. I want to change the url bar to about/contact.

I used this.

```
window.location.replace = about/contact;
```

But now, he redirect direct to this page. But I do not want, that the page is redirect to that url. How can i fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can not do that. However, you could add an anchor to the URL which does not reload the page, e.g. `www.example.com#about`

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: @w4rumy [Are you sure about that?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). CNTRL + F **Adding and modifying history entries**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the History API, though [support is not universal yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=history), though good in browsers other than IE. For an example of it in use: http://html5demos.com/history. It will modify the visible URL as you want, and will also allow you to use the back button to go back to previous states.

Suggest you use something like [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) to this as it behaves accordingly for browsers that do not yet support the history API. It will use the History API first, and if that isn't present will use the [hash](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/hashbang-and-pushstate) technique.

If you want to do-it-yourself, then definately look up on the History API and how it works, here's some places to start: [article 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), [article 2](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/)

Comment: I would highly suggest adding [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Which requires no API and is supported amongst many modern browsers.

Comment: Good link @Ohgodwhy, have added it. The main reason I suggest history.js is because of how it acts as a sort of polyfill for browsers with no support

Answer (score 2):

Use the ajax history plugin, like jquery-address.

Look at this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin